# how to make a function execute in model without calling in controller ,YII framework

Tags: php, yii

In my yii based sample project I have a model named gateway and this model has a variable from DB with name **$time** that is a creation time for gateway 
that comes from php time() function.

I want to change this variable to a readable form to show in view (not to save in DB) and for this I wrote a function **setTime()** and defined a variable **$readabletime**

I didn't call function **settime()** in controller but in **rules()** of model

I wrote this line:

```
array('time','setTime')
```

but it doesn,t work

How can I make a function work in model?

This is my model

```
<?php


class UserGateway extends CActiveRecord
{
public $readabletime; 
/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'user_gateway';
}


public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('name, url, ip, time, userid, gatewaycategoryid', 'required'),
        array('time, status, userid, gatewaycategoryid, defaultgateway', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('name, url', 'length', 'max'=>120),
        array('ip', 'length', 'max'=>18),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, name, url, ip, time, status, userid, gatewaycategoryid, defaultgateway', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        array('time','setTime')
    );
}

public function setTime()
{
    $this->readabletime=date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $this->time);
}

}
```

and this is my view:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-    button')); ?>

<div class="search-form" style="display:none">

</div><!-- search-form -->

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'UserAccountnumber-grid',

'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),

'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'name',
     'url',
    'ip',
    'readabletime',

    array(

        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'buttons'=>array(
                'update' => array(
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(\'User/UpdateGateway\',array(\'id\'=>$data[id]))'),
                'delete' => array(
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(\'User/DeleteGateway\',array(\'id\'=>$data[id]))'

                        ),                            ),
                )
            )             
      )        
  );
  ?>
```

thank you all for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just write `afterFind` function in your model:

```
protected function afterFind()
{
    // convert to readable time format while viewing
    $this->readabletime = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $this->time);

    parent::afterFind();
}
```

This way wherever `readabletime` is used, it will convert it to your desired format. [CActiveRecord afterFind](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail)

Answer (score 0):

1) Validation rules and their functions are only called on `$model->validate()`.

2) You've just hijacked Yii's native method for setting database properties without calling the parent, meaning your `setTime()` function will be called when something like this is done: `$model->time = time()`; meaning `time` will never get set on the internal array of database attributes; meaning a time value will never be saved in the database.  Conclusion: don't do that.

3) There are a couple ways you can accomplish this.

i.  Override the `afterFind()` (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail) function, and set `$readdabletime` equal to a formatted version of time.  This will be called right after your model properties are loaded from the database (make sure to call `parent::afterFind()` at the bottom of your function.

ii. Remove the line, `public $readdabletime;`, and add this function to your code instead:

```
public function getReaddabletime() {
    return date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $this->time);
}
```

The formatted time will be accessible like this: `$model->readdabletime`

Answer (score 0):

In your model simply do

```
public function getTime(){
     return date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $this->time);
}
```

Then, in CGridView

```
'url',
'ip',
array(
    'name' => 'Readable time',
    'value' => $model->getTime()
),
...
```